# MVC Required Textbox with JQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC form that has 3 required fields. A Name textbox, a Dropdown list and a textbox with the JQuery DatePicker attached to it. If the form is submitted and there is nothing selected, the form gets rejected and text appears next to the fields stating it is required. After I select a date from the JQuery DatePicker textbox the required text is still there, this is not the case with the other two required inputs. Any idea how to fix this?

Here are some images:

[image: Required Date]

**After I select a date**

[image]

**Model**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
public string Requestor { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name="Date Requested")]
public DateTime?  Date_Requested { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string Process { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requestor)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Requestor) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Requestor)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_Requested)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date_Requested,new {@class="datepicker" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_Requested)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Approved_Date)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Approved_Date,new {@class="datepicker" }) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Approved_Date)
</div>
```

**JQuery**
This is where I found the code [JQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datepicker`'s `onSelect` event and in there call `valid()` on your date field.

According to `datepicker` documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect `this` in `onSelect` refers to the associated text field, so you can simply do this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect : function() {
        $(this).valid();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not 100% sure where to add this. I added by current JQuery which isn't much but it seems to add the calendar

Comment: I modified my answer to include the code. It's untested, but should be along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

This post has been here for a couple of years, but there is more to the answer that I thought I'd add ...since I ran into the same issue.  Whenever my form was submitted without picking a date using the jQuery datepicker, I would get a client side validation error saying '***DateProcessed field is required.***' ... But I couldn't see *anything* that would make the field required!

model:

```
// No attributes applied ([Required] or otherwise in my case)    
public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

model initialization:

```
DateProcessed = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Form.cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateProcessed, new { id = "DateProcessedDatePicker", placeholder = " MM/dd/yyyy" })
```

Script in .ready() (in Form.cshtml):

```
$('#DateProcessedDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' })
```

So what was happening?  It appears that if your date field is initialized to DateTime.MinValue, that it becomes a null value in the datepicker (and the handy placeholder text shows up).  But the model's date field above is a non-nullable DateTime field which cannot be set to null (by ignoring the datepicker and not selecting a date).  The solution, assuming the date is NOT required, is to first change the field to a nullable DateTime (below), then second, make sure the code that depends on or utilizes this field works properly even if it is null:

```
// No attributes applied ([Required] or otherwise in my case)    
public DateTime? DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

Enjoy!
Brian